# Objects allowed in a SQL ER diagram

Tags: sql, uml, erd

My assignment requires that I have an ER diagram that shows the dependencies between the objects in my solution. Mine consists of several procedures, tables, a trigger and a sequence. Does anyone know if these objects are permitted in a SQL ER diagram? I ask this because the example shown by my lecturer consisted only of tables. If these objects are allowed in an ER diagram, what is the proper way to represent them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an ER diagram should not contain procedures, triggers nor sequences.

An Entity-Relashioship Diagram is used to represent the relashionships between entities in a database. Procedures, triggers and sequences do not contribute to the relashionship representations.

Answer (score 0):

ER Diagram don't have any particular representation of triggers because ER-Diagram is logical design of Database. BUT we use Strong entity and weak entity symbols to show the dependence of tables
[Strong Weak](http://chamin89.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/weakentity2.jpg?w=700)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Entities (the squares), Relationships (the diamonds) and attributes (the ellipsis). All of them are connected by simple lines.

Finally, and most important. Entities and Relationships are not Tables, as you say. Those are part of a physical model.